# PHP - skip display duplicate fields(not records) in MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

My code is just query a database and output to a HTML table:

```
<?php

  include("incl\dbcon.php");

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM attendanceRecord";

  $result = $db_con->query($sql);

  echo "<table>
  <tr>
  <th>Date</th>
  <th>Building Name</th>
  <th>Room Name</th>
  <th>Student</th>
  <th>Time</th>
  </tr>";

  while($row_result = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row_result['rDate'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row_result['rBuildingName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row_result['rRoomName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row_result['rStudent'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row_result['rTime'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
  }

  $db_con->close();

  echo "</table>";

?>
```

the result is like:

```
Date         Building Name    Room Name  Student    Time
2018-07-12   Building A       1A         Sam        08:32:33
2018-07-12   Building A       1A         David      08:54:21
2018-07-12   Building A       1A         Dragon     08:50:10
2018-07-12   Building A       1B         John       08:43:11
2018-07-12   Building A       1B         Coco       08:51:39
2018-07-12   Building B       3A         Mary       08:21:23
2018-07-12   Building B       3A         Martin     08:46:57
2018-07-12   Building B       4B         Ray        08:26:47
```

How can I don't show or empty the duplicate fields in a row and make the table looks like below?

```
Date         Building Name    Room Name  Student    Time
2018-07-12   Building A       1A         Sam        08:32:33
                                         David      08:54:21
                                         Dragon     08:50:10
                              1B         John       08:43:11
                                         Coco       08:51:39
             Building B       3A         Mary       08:21:23
                                         Martin     08:46:57
                              4B         Ray        08:26:47
```

Where should i approach? from sql query(don't know is there a function to empty or NULL duplicate fields while query) or php array(print NULL if duplicate then move the pointer?), please help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Why you are trying to do it on mysql side? It is a matter of data presentation and should be done in view logic of app.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I am not insist doing it on mysql side, just trying to find a solution in an appropriate way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the rows always come out in the right order (you can use ORDER BY to ensure it!) then in the PHP, keep a variable which contains the value of the date from the previous row. If it matches the date on the current row, don't print that value in the td. If it doesn't, then print it, as it must be a new one. Same approach for the Building name and Room name, but within the context of the current date (and building):

```
$date = "";
$buildingName = ""; //declare these outside the loop so they persist between loops
$roomName = "";

while($row_result = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . ($row_result['rDate'] == $date ? "" : $row_result['rDate']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .($row_result['rBuildingName'] == $buildingName $row_result['rDate'] == $date ? "" : $row_result['rBuildingName']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . ($row_result['rRoomName'] == $roomName && $row_result['rBuildingName'] == $buildingName && $row_result['rDate'] == $date ? "" : $row_result['rRoomName']) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row_result['rStudent'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row_result['rTime'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    //update the references to the specific fields
    $date = $row_result['rDate'];
    $buildingName = $row_result['rRoomName'];
    $roomName = $row_result['rRoomName'];
}
```

P.S. I would never attempt to do this in SQL, since it's really specific to the presentation of the data in this particular context, rather than the nature of the data itself. It's also much simpler in PHP.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! will try it tonight and get back to you!

Comment: Dude, your answer is exactly what i want, thank for the teaching!

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can do something like this

```
  include("incl\dbcon.php");

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM attendanceRecord";

  $result = $db_con->query($sql);

  echo "<table>
  <tr>
  <th>Date</th>
  <th>Building Name</th>
  <th>Room Name</th>
  <th>Student</th>
  <th>Time</th>
  </tr>";

  $rDate = $rBuildingName = $rRoomName = $rStudent = $rTime = [];

  while($row_result = $result->fetch_assoc()){

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . (!in_array(  $row_result['rDate'] , $rDate) ? $row_result['rDate'] : ''). "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . (!in_array(  $row_result['rBuildingName'] , $rBuildingName) ? $row_result['rBuildingName'] : '') . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . (!in_array(  $row_result['rRoomName'] , $rRoomName) ? $row_result['rRoomName'] : '') . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . (!in_array(  $row_result['rStudent'] , $rStudent) ? $row_result['rStudent'] : '') . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . (!in_array(  $row_result['rTime'] , $rTime) ? $row_result['rTime'] : '') . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    $rDate[] = $row_result['rDate'];
    $rBuildingName[] = $row_result['rBuildingName'];
    $rRoomName[] = $row_result['rRoomName'];
    $rStudent[] = $row_result['rStudent'];
    $rTime[] = $row_result['rTime'];


  }

  $db_con->close();

  echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Why should OP _do something like this_? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @B001ᛦ i think it is self-explanatory, should it explain ternary operator here?

Comment: Thanks for your answer!, will digest and try it tonight!